# Почему появляется горизонтальный скроллбар при height: 100vh;?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend, адаптивная-верстка

появляется горизонтальная прокрутка при выставленном на .container-1 height в 100vh, при значении меньше все нормально. Почему так происходит?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}

.container-1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container-1">
    Content-1
  </div>  
  <div class="container-2">
    Content-2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100vw берет всю ширину окна браузера, но поскольку у вас container-2 уезжает под container-1, появляется еще вертикальная прокрутка, которую 100vw не учитывает. В итоге получается смещение и скролл

Попробуйте для container-1 поставить например `height: calc(100vh - 50px);` (чтобы оба блока влезли в экран), увидите, что горизонтальный скролл пропадет вместе с вертикальным

В качестве решения можно на wrapper прописать `overflow-x: hidden;`, но тут уже зависит от Ваших конкретных целей на верстку.

Кстати, по-умолчанию div-блок занимает всю доступную ширину (если это не переопределено), так что можете просто убрать 100vw, и все будет ок